# Android splash screen with animation works only for KitKat

Tags: android, android-animation, splash-screen

i have the following code and it works great for android 4.4 KitKat.

In the other android version the animation @anim/loading_animation is showing but not moving.

Someone can help me?? Thank you so much!!

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {                
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

**splash_screen.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/Black" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:src="@anim/loading_animation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check your manifest file and minimum SK version. Change it to API 8.I hope it works.
If you still face any issue. let me know